# Wordpress Migration error phpupdate_option is not a function

Tags: functions, migration

I'm trying to migrate my wordpress from a subfolde to the root.
I've already done it from localhost to the subfolder with the same method

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com/blog');
update_option('home','http://example.com/blog');
```

But this time it does not look to work...
It says "Call to undefined function phpupdate_option() in functions.php line 1.

In config.php there is no url define().

Is there someone who had a solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your opening `<?php` tag is abutting your first call to update_option. If it isn't directly adjacent to it, perhaps the whitespace between the two is unrecognized for one reason or another (this can happen from copying and pasting from some sources). Have your functions.php file start off like this:

```
<?php

update_option('siteurl','http://example.com/blog');
update_option('home','http://example.com/blog');
```

Comment: yes, I put some space between <?php and the function. I mean... is it a white space problem?

Comment: If I take it out, all the other functions work, then no matter how many whit line I put, it's always telling me "line 1" even if it's in line 3 or 4 or 100...

Comment: Try this: between the `<?php` and `update_option`, put a couple of newlines and a comment. Something like, `/* this is a comment */`. I suspect it's your code editor; maybe it's adding CR (mac) newlines, and PHP isn't parsing them. The comment should break it up no matter what. Add a space after `<?php` too, it won't hurt. We're going fishing with grenades ;-)

Comment: I fixed it, I just put one space with the spacebar and it works, apparently he didn't like the enter...

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from database also.
In database there is wp_options table and these two fields present in this table.

Comment: Yes, I could, but this problem just came out and I want to understand why first.